# Can' open File in C++ under MacOs

Tags: c++, qt, ifstream

I want to open and read a file in C++. Therefor I wrote the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
    ...
    
string line;
ifstream file;
file.open("./db.config");
if (file.is_open()) {
    cout << "File is open" << endl;
    getline(file, line);
    file.close();
}else cout << "File is not open" << endl;
```

This code is written in the main.cpp. I verified that main.cpp and db.config are in the same directory.[image]

I don't get any Compiletime oder Runtime Errors. It only prints "File is not open". I also tried it without "./" ( file.open("db.config"); ), but this also didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you put the absolute path of db.config there?

Comment: Yes that works. But is there any way I could also make it work with the relative Path, as this should not only work on my machine.

Comment: `file.open("./db.config");` or even just `file.open("db.config");` will attempt to locate `db.config` from the **current working directory** (cwd), and not necessarily the directory holding your executable.  (e.g., whatever directory you were at when you typed the command to run your program is likely the cwd).  And that's even less likely to be the same directory as your source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, the current working directory is not the one where `db.config` file is located. You seem to have it in the same directory as the *.cpp* file. The current working directory is probably something different. Ultimately you need to decide where you want `db.config` file to reside, there are many options, but here's simple solution:

1. See where the application binary is.
2. Copy `db.config` there if it isn't there already.
3. In your code, change to that directory before you load the file, which you can do with Qt like this:
   `QDir::setCurrent(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());`

Note that if the user runs the program from command line, and are allowed to give files as arguments, then changing working directory inside the program might make those files not be found. In that case, construct absolute path to `db.config` instead of changing the working directory.

---

You could read [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) docs to get better idea on where you actually *want* to store the `db.config` file. This depends on how you plan to distribute the application. If you just want to have it in `.zip` or something, then same directory with application binary is probably fine.